# Throwing in another room when you enter the room

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When someone walks in one room I want them to throw it in another room

This is the code

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", function(oldMember, newMember){

let room = client.channels.cache.get('586962325240676370');
let newVoice = newMember.voice.channelID
     
if (newVoice == room){
let channelgit = client.channels.cache.get('757403475129794600')    
member.voice.setChannel(channelgit);
    }
});
```

I get this error

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\proton mdul\index.js:44
     let newVoice = newMember.voice.channelID
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'channelID' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\proton mdul\index.js:44:37)
    at Client.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at VoiceStateUpdate.handle (C:\Users\user\Desktop\proton mdul\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\VoiceStateUpdate.js:40:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as VOICE_STATE_UPDATE] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\proton mdul\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\VOICE_STATE_UPDATE.js:4:35)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\proton mdul\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\proton mdul\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\proton mdul\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\proton mdul\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\proton mdul\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

Comment: error's pretty clear: `newMember.voice` is nothing (it's undefined).

Comment: How can I get the "voice channel id" of someone connecting to any voice channel?

Comment: no idea, I know nothing about Discord, I just know JS (you know more about discord than I do) So: check the API documentation? All I can tell you is that the error is telling you that there is no "voice" property on "newMember" and you should probably at the very least console.log `newMember` to see what it is.

Comment: the listener you use here gives you a [`voiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) to work with. Thats what you need to use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `voiceStateUpdate` event actually returns `oldState` and `newState` in the newest version of discord.js ([source](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate)) which are both `VoiceState` objects, not `GuildMember` objects.

Therefore, you'll have to change your code to use `VoiceState` instead. This is pretty simple, as you can get a `GuildMember` object from a `VoiceState` by getting the `.member` property.

Another thing is that `newState` can sometimes be `undefined` because the event also fires when someone **leaves** a voice channel. This means you'll also have to check if the value is undefined or not.

If you were to implement all of this changes, it would look something like this:

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", function(oldState, newState) {
    if (newState === undefined) {
        return;
    }

    let room = client.channels.cache.get('586962325240676370');
    let voiceChannelID = newState.channelID;

    if (voiceChannelID === room) {
        let channelgit = client.channels.cache.get('757403475129794600');
        newState.setChannel(channelgit);
    }
});
```